# First show the profile clicked then swipe between profiles react native

Tags: react-native

Hi how can I first show the user that I've clicked on and then display a swiper ? I can't find a logic for that. I have a list of users and when I click on one, it should open a new component where we will find more infos about that user. Then I want to swipe between the list of users on the same component of the description ?

Here are my user profile component and the flatlist :

```
render () {
    var colorConnected;
            if (this.props.navigation.getParam('Statut') === "ON") {
              colorConnected = "#1fbc26";
            }
            else if (this.props.navigation.getParam('Statut') === "OFF") {
              colorConnected = "#ff0303";
            }
            else {
              colorConnected = "#ffd200";
            }
    return (
         <Swiper showsPagination={false}>
            {this.state.items.map((item, key) => {
            return (
                <ScrollView style = {styles.view_container}>
                    <View style={styles.photo}>
                      <ImageBackground source={{uri:this.props.navigation.getParam('Photo')}} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                        <View style={styles.photo_content}>
                          <LinearGradient colors={['transparent', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)']} style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, height: 80 }} />
                          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View>
                              <Text style={{ fontSize: 40, color:'white' }}>{this.props.navigation.getParam('Age')}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ marginRight: 7, marginLeft: 7, backgroundColor: '#ffffff', width: 1, height: 39 }}></View>
                              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', flex:1 }}>
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                  <View style={[styles.bulle_presence, { backgroundColor: colorConnected } ]}></View>
                                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: '600', color:'white' }}>{this.props.navigation.getParam('Pseudo')}</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color:'white' }}>{this.props.navigation.getParam('Distance')}</Text>
                                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, color:'white'}}>{this.props.navigation.getParam('Genre')}</Text>
                                </View>
                              </View>
                          </View>
                        </View>
               </ImageBackgroud>
           </View>
      </ScrollView>
  )
            })}
  </Swiper>
)}
}
```

```
render() {
    GLOBAL.data = this.state.dataSource;
    //console.log(GLOBAL.data);
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <View style={styles.main_container}>
          <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          extraData = {this.state}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.MembreId}
          renderItem={(item) => <UserItem user={item} displayDetailForUser={this._displayDetailForUser} />}
          numColumns={numColumns}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh} />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
 }
```

With this code, I'm only able to swipe on the user where I've clicked. The others user are not showing.

Comment: try to see this native-based component: https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#deckswiper-def-headref

Answer (score 1):

You can open a modal then use a carousel like [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel) in full screen mode to generate your use case

Comment: How can I do that ?